# Web push notifications ios 16.4

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

Apple has finally enabled web push on ios!!! Great, but I see some unexpected behavior: on ios my PWA will receive a notification even when it is open and in the forefront, contrary to Android or Desktop where it is triggered only when it is not in the forefront.

How do I get to show the web push only if my PWA is not in the forefront?

I use ios 16.4 and Firebase FCM